# Movie with elfin characters, a girl having a vision, and an adventurer boy

Tags: story-identification, movie

I was sitting next to someone on the train who was watching a movie with subtitles. I saw a title flash for a minute - something about it being part of chronicles or something like that.

The first part was a girl having a vision or dream, where she saw a castle all gray, with some sort of monster standing over the very wounded body of a girl with a bloody face. She screams, and the scene changes.

A man with strange lines on his face wakes up on the floor and says some sort of line about accepting the magic of the Earth. He trembles and the stick he is holding turns into a spear or sword.

A boy rides a horse up to his home, where he is told he is too late. He goes inside and his mother is dying. She tells him he is a sweet boy and to find the druid. Then she dies and he mourns her.

Back at the girl who had the vision. She is in her room, she is wearing some sort of fancy gown and girl brings a boy to her room and tells her maybe she will be willing to talk to him. This must be her boyfriend or something like that, he teases her about a picture of a monster she has drawn. He tells her there is no more magic. He convinces her to go gout to the people - she seems to be a ruler or heiress or something. She speaks to them and then touches a wall and has another vision of a boy mortally injured. All the characters in her part of the story have pointy ears.

Back to the boy whose mother died, he is riding his horse and weapon knocks him off his horse. He looks around and suddenly a monster is next to him and then knocked down, a girl appears who apparently did both attacks and she saved him.

A boy is touching some sort of tree respectfully when another male grabs him.

That's where I got off the train. Any idea what this is?

Comment: The Shannara Chronicles? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shannara_Chronicles

Comment: @CBredlow yes! Put as answer and I'll mark it correct. Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, I would strongly recommend to read the books and not watch the series. Not as in the usual "books are always better" opinion, but because the series - unlike the books - are not aimed to an adult/intelligent audience but to teens. So instead of epic fantasy, you get hopeless teenage drivel, horrible script, horrible acting, horrible dialogue. So don't expect another GoT. The only thing they did right was to start from book 2, as the 1st book Sword of Shannara was a shameless LOTR rip-off.

Comment: @Amarth they could have done the scions series as a starting point

Comment: @CBredlow Or they could have used proper writers, director, producer. Not some brainwashed Hollywood goons... Always disgusts me when such a goon for some reason thinks he is better at writing a story than a professional fantasy author with some 10+ books behind them. Add horrible acting on top of that. I like Terry Brooks but I just couldn't stand watching these series, the quality was plain horrible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sounds a lot like [*The Shannara Chronicles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shannara_Chronicles), which was based on the "Elfstones of Shannara" book by Terry Brooks

The girl, Amberle, is an elf related to the main elven bloodline of the Westlands.

The boy is Wil Ohmsford, who wields magic stones called the Elfstones.

The druid is Allanon, who is a prominent figure in almost all of the Shannara books.

Comment: To add. That person wasn't watching a movie but the Netflix series with the same name. 2 Seasons are released so far. A 3th is still pending to be made last time I checked

Comment: @Taacoo A 3th? :-)